# How to make my application be considered as a communication program in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, audio, directsound

I'm making a program that uses the Speech library and I'd like to get all other sounds muted or reduced when the lady is talking.

I've been looking for a way to mute other applications manually, but I've seen an option in Windows in the communication tab (inside the sound options) that mentions that window can manage this for me. Like in this picture:

[image]

So basically, what does it take for my application to be considered as a communication application (such as Skype)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940522(v=vs.85).aspx may be relevant. Haven't looked at it in enough detail to write an answer.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is what you are looking for. Never used it myself, so i can't give you a proper way how to register you program as such an application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the communication apps are implementing something related to the [`IAudioVolumeDuckNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371006%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interface. The C++ example provided also references `WM_VOLUME_DUCK` and `WM_VOLUME_UNDUCK` windows messages which may be enough (but don't appear to be google-able or documented).

**UPDATE**

The [.NET Core Audio API project](http://netcoreaudio.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex appears to provide a .NET wrapper.

**UPDATE**

A sample C++ implementation of `IAudioVolumeDuckNotification` as well as an example of notifying the `ducked` state can be found in the MSDN [`DuckingMediaPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sample application. It actually works (I tried it). A combination of PInvoke'ing a couple methods and the .NET wrapper for the interface should be enough to get you on your way.